# Set stretch/height/width property for a generic custom button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, visual-studio-2008

I am using a custom generic button from an assembly which it is not mine. In my xaml I set the xml namespace as:

```
xmlns:styleBtn="clr-namespace:Utils.XAML.ButtonsStyle;assembly=Utils.XAML"
```

Then in xaml I use it as below:

```
<styleBtn:GenericButton x:Name="btnSearch" Height="28" Width="100" ImgButton="/PathToResource/Search.png" 
                        TextButton="Search"
                        Click="btnSearch_Click"/>
```

As seen above, this custom generic button has some custom properties like ImgButton, TextButton among others.

My problem here is when I set an image that is bigger than the size of the button(height=28, width=100), in this case I cannot set the height/width of the image passed through the ImgButton property, so image does not fit correctly within the button.

So Is there any way to set the size of the image externally? Of course, I always can use another smaller image, but for curiosity, Would it be possible to set size of the image passed?

Comment: What is the type of the `ImgButton` property?

Comment: @EdPlunkett it's Image.source

Comment: Do you mean [`ImageSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @EdPlunkett No, it is the same when you create an <Image> object and sets de property Source. It is the same type as Source. If I set the background of the button instead? I have tried to set background by assigning background property from a resource ImageBrush but it is not working.

Comment: You can try to examine what specific element (`Image`) holds an image inside `GenericButton` and place style for this element in `GenericButton.Resources` where you set size of it.

Comment: @Maxim Yes, I know which is, the element which holds the image is an Image object. When I set the ImgButton it is bind to the source property of an Image object. so how to do what you say? an example?

Comment: `<GenericButton.Resources><Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}"><Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"/></Style></GenericButton.Resources>` It's worth a try to play with this approach.

Comment: @Maxim Wowwww this works! but instead of setting property Stretch I have set Height and Width properties to fit within the button. Thanks man! Please post the answer here and I will vote for you!

Comment: @user1624552 Answer is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set desired properties of inner `Image` of the `GenericButton` in `Style` placed inside `GenericButton.Resources`:

```
<GenericButton.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="..."/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="..."/>
    </Style>
</GenericButton.Resources>
```